# Что за методы removeAll и retainAll?

Tags: java, коллекции

В гугле наткнулся только на такое описание:

> `removeAll(Collection c)` — удаляет элементы, принадлежащие переданной коллекции
>   `retainAll(Collection c)` — удаляет элементы, не принадлежащие переданной коллекции

Что значит "принадлежащие переданной коллекции" и "не принадлежащие переданной коллекции"?

Comment: не принадлежащие переданной коллекции - значит если есть элементы, которых нет в переданной коллекции, то нужно удалить и из первой (к которой применяется метод)......принадлежащие переданной коллекции - соответственно, если есть элемент и первой и во второй (переданной) коллекции, то дубль из первой уничтожается.......а вообще там `Retains only the elements in this set that are contained in the specified collection` - перевод: Сохраняет только те элементы в этом наборе, которые содержатся в указанном наборе

Comment: @АлексейШиманский "то нужно удалить **и** из первой" - т.е. из 2 коллекции они тоже удаляются?

Comment: это была опечатка) "**их** из первой" или даже не "их", а "аналогичные значения в первой коллекции" ..... Собственно Suvitruf привел примеры в ответе

Comment: @АлексейШиманский А можно сделать вот так(для примера имена коллекций) - List.removeAll(set);

Comment: Но ведь у вас наверняка IDE есть, почему бы не проверить? ;-)  ........ Но вообще можно. Потому что removeAll - это метод класса Collection. А set и list они унаследованы от него........можете даже поискать в интернете схемы иерархии  http://java5tutor.info/images/collectionhierarchy.jpg

Comment: @АлексейШиманский ну да) после реганья на SO я стал об этом забывать)))) , а иерархия у меня перед глазами))) 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/cW3xJ.png

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Предположим у вас коллекция есть:

```
List<String> listFirst = new ArrayList<>();  
listFirst.add("White");  
listFirst.add("Black");  
listFirst.add("Red");
```

и вторая:

```
List<String> listSecond = new ArrayList<>();  

listSecond.add("Green");   
listSecond.add("Red");   
listSecond.add("White");
```

Тогда после `listFirst.retainAll(listSecond)` в `listFirst` останется:

```
"White"
"Red"
```

Так как удалился "Black", которого нет в `listSecond`.

Но после `listFirst.removeAll(listSecond)` в `listFirst` останется:

```
"Black"
```

Удалились все элементы, которые есть в `listSecond`.

Comment: Я знаю где взят ответ :-P  я вот думаю, может стоит ссылку оставить на ориг/английский вариант?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский я обычно ссылки оставляю, если ссылаюсь ответ на en SO. В данном случае по ссылке больше ничего нового автор вопроса не найдёт уже)

Comment: ну просто там копирование контента, права, все дела. Я то лично не против. Ну ладн, пока пусть будет так)